# How to create multiple flag columns based on list values found in the dataframe column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, hive, pyspark, data-manipulation

The table looks like this :

```
     ID  |CITY
    ----------------------------------
    1  |London|Paris|Tokyo
    2  |Tokyo|Barcelona|Mumbai|London
    3  |Vienna|Paris|Seattle
```

The city column contains around 1000+ values which are | delimited

I want to create a flag column to indicate if a person visited only the city of interest.

```
    city_of_interest=['Paris','Seattle','Tokyo']
```

There are 20 such values in the list.

Ouput should look like this :

```
     ID      |Paris   | Seattle | Tokyo    
     -------------------------------------------
     1       |1       |0        |1      
     2       |0       |0        |1       
     3       |1       |1        |0
```

The solution can either be in pandas or pyspark.

Comment: can you include your attempt as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For pyspark, use [split](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) + [array_contains](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, array_contains

df.withColumn('cities', split('CITY', '\|')) \
  .select('ID', *[ array_contains('cities', c).astype('int').alias(c) for c in city_of_interest ]) 
  .show()
+---+-----+-------+-----+
| ID|Paris|Seattle|Tokyo|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|  1|    1|      0|    1|
|  2|    0|      0|    1|
|  3|    1|      1|    0|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
```

For Pandas, use [Series.str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html?highlight=get_dummies#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies):

```
df[city_of_interest] = df.CITY.str.get_dummies()[city_of_interest]
df = df.drop('CITY', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Pandas Solution**

First transform to list to use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
new_df=df.copy()
new_df['CITY']=new_df['CITY'].str.lstrip('|').str.split('|')
#print(new_df)

#   ID                                CITY
#0   1              [London, Paris, Tokyo]
#1   2  [Tokyo, Barcelona, Mumbai, London]
#2   3            [Vienna, Paris, Seattle]
```

---

Then we can use:

**Method 1:** [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
new_df=( new_df.explode('CITY')
               .pivot_table(columns='CITY',index='ID',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)
               [city_of_interest]
               .reset_index()
               .rename_axis(columns=None)
                )
print(new_df)
```

**Method 2:** [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
new_df=( new_df.explode('CITY')
               .groupby(['ID'])
               .CITY
               .value_counts()
               .unstack('CITY',fill_value=0)[city_of_interest]
               .reset_index()
               .rename_axis(columns=None)

                )
print(new_df)
```

**Output new_df:**

```
   ID  Paris  Seattle  Tokyo
0   1      1        0      1
1   2      0        0      1
2   3      1        1      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a UDF to check if the city of interest value is in the delimited column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

#Input list
city_of_interest=['Paris','Seattle','Tokyo']

#UDF definition
def city_present(city_name,city_list):
    return len(set([city_name]) & set(city_list.split('|')))

city_present_udf = udf(city_present,IntegerType())

#Converting cities list to a column of array type for adding columns to the dataframe
city_array = array(*[lit(city) for city in city_of_interest])
l = len(city_of_interest)
col_names = df.columns + [city for city in city_of_interest]
result = df.select(df.columns + [city_present_udf(city_array[i],df.city) for i in range(l)])
result = result.toDF(*col_names)
result.show()
```